# How to generate HTML color diff from git using python

Tags: python, git, file-io

So I figured out creating HTML git diff i can embed in email but don't know why is it all being spit in one line ?

here is how I did it!!

```
import sys
import subprocess
import os

from ansi2html.converter import Ansi2HTMLConverter



ansiText =  os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/colorDiff')


pr = subprocess.Popen( "git diff HEAD^ HEAD --color > "+ansiText , cwd = os.getcwd() , shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE )
(out, error) = pr.communicate()

conv = Ansi2HTMLConverter()
ansi = ''
with open(ansiText, 'r+') as fh:
    fh.readline()

    for line in fh:
        ansi += ''.join(line.split())

html = conv.convert(ansi)

with open("%s.html" % ansiText, 'w+') as wf:
    wf.write(html)

os.remove(ansiText)
print str(error).capitalize()
```

maybe its too late to be awake...

Comment: When you use `with open ...`, you don't  have to close the file handle.

Comment: that i realised however that is not my question.

Comment: Luckily for you san hughdbrown didn't post an answer, just a comment.

Comment: @ejbs : i figured out, see answer ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured out myself

```
import sys
import subprocess
import os

from ansi2html.converter import Ansi2HTMLConverter



ansiText =  os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/colorDiff')



proc = subprocess.Popen('git diff HEAD^ HEAD --color',  shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE )
diffData = proc.stdout.read()
conv = Ansi2HTMLConverter()

html = conv.convert(diffData)


with open("%s.html" % ansiText, 'w') as wf:
    wf.write(html)
```

Comment: i have some refactoring pending which i will do later when i get back !!

Comment: In your original, you called `fh.readline` and then called `for line in fh`, effectively stripping off the first line of the file. That is not replicated in this code sample.

Comment: If there is an error from `communicate`, you should handle the error immediately and stop.

Comment: It would be more idiomatic to join your test together all at once: `html = "".join(conv.convert(line) for line in fh.read().split("\n"))`.